# Extracting results from Pandas GroupBy function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am relatively new to Python and started to use Pandas. I've looked at the Pandas documentation but can't see to find what I need although that could be due to being unfamiliar with some of the terminology.

I used the Dataframe GroupBy function and have these results

```
mean_len = spam.groupby(spam.target).mean()

Function      Mean
   A          1.5
   B          2.6
```

My question is, what code would generate the result below from the groupby output:

```
(1.5, 2.6)
```

thanks a lot

Comment: `tuple(df.groupby('A')['B'].mean())` will work ? if you return a series

Answer (score 0):

This should convert it to a tuple:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Function': ['A', 'B'],
    'Mean': [1.5, 2.5]
})
a = tuple(list(df['Mean']))
print(a)

(1.5, 2.5)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot NYC Coder - much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the series Mean as a numpy array using

```
means = mean_len.Mean.values
```

If what you actually want is a list or a tuple, you can additionally do

```
tuple(means.tolist())
```

Comment: Thanks very much Suvansh